# PL/pgSQL: How to use IF NEW.<variable_column_name> <> OLD.<variable_column_name>

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am pretty new to PL/pgSQL programming. I have a requirement of audit logging updated columns in my table

Table

```
create table sample_table(name varchar(15),city varchar(15),age int,mail varchar(20) primary key);
```

Audit table

```
create table sample_table__audits_dynamicols(mail varchar(20), columnchanged varchar(10), oldvalue varchar(10), changed_on timestamp(6) NOT NULL)
```

Trigger Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.log_sample_table_allchanges() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$DECLARE
       _colname text;
       _tablename varchar(15) := 'sample_table';
       _schema varchar(15) := 'public';
       _changed_on time := now();
    BEGIN
      FOR _colname IN SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.Columns WHERE table_schema = _schema AND table_name = _tablename LOOP  
         IF NEW._colname <> OLD._colname THEN
            INSERT INTO sample_table__audits_dynamicols(mail,columnchanged, oldvalue ,changed_on)
            VALUES(OLD.mail,_colname,OLD.:_colname,_changed_on);
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
     RETURN NEW;
    END$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
```

Trigger

```
create TRIGGER log_sample_table_allchanges
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON SAMPLE_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_sample_table_allchanges();
```

Requirement: Whenever a column value is changed i want to log it as

(mail, columnname, columnvalue, date)

E.g:

```
insert into sample_table (name, mail, city, age) values('kanta','mk@foo.com','hyd',23);
insert into sample_table (name, mail, city, age) values('kmk','mk@gmail.com','hyd',23);
```

So when i update like the following

```
update sample_table set age=24 where mail='mk@foo.com';
update sample_table set city='bza' where mail='mk@gmail.com'
```

I want audit table to record like

```
(mk@foo.com,age,23, timestamp) 
(mk@gmail.com, city, hyd, timestamp)
```

Right now I am facing issue with column comparison in my Trigger function. Please help me rectifying my Trigger function to meet my requirement.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i want to iterate over all the columns of '"sample_table" and check whether any column value is updated or not. I was facing issue in accessing the column names dynamically. My issue got resolved now. Please check the solution provided by Kaushik below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `EXECUTE` to get the values of columns dynamically and do the comparison.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_sample_table_allchanges() RETURNS trigger AS 
    $BODY$
      DECLARE
       _colname text;
       _tablename varchar(15) := 'sample_table';
       _schema varchar(15) := 'public';
       _changed_on timestamp := now();
       _old_val text;
       _new_val text;
    BEGIN
      FOR _colname IN SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.Columns WHERE table_schema = _schema AND table_name = _tablename
       LOOP  
          EXECUTE 'SELECT $1.' || _colname || ', $2.' || _colname
           USING OLD,NEW
          INTO _old_val, _new_val; --get the old and new values for the column.

          IF _new_val <> _old_val THEN
            INSERT INTO sample_table__audits_dynamicols(mail,columnchanged, oldvalue ,changed_on)
            VALUES(OLD.mail,_colname,_old_val,_changed_on);
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
     RETURN NEW;
    END$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
```

I'm not sure why you have defined `mail` as a `PRIMARY KEY` in the audits table, it will cause `unique constraint` violation if the same mail gets updated twice.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, yes you are correct the Primary key constraint in audit table is incorrect. I have re-created my audit table and modified my trigger function as specified in your answer. It worked. Thankyou so much !!!

Comment: @ManiKantaKandagatla : You're welcome. By the way, the question you asked had all the details required, exactly how a question in Stackoverflow should be.Greatly appreciated.